# Socket closed exception and control never returned back

Tags: spring-boot, ssh, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I am very new Spring Integration SFTP and I writing code to do SFTP file upload to SFTP server. It always fails at jsch Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
and I see that the execution never gets completed. Please advise.

Comment: Same JSCH log found at [GitHub - rundeck issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/699). Doesn't seem to have a solution though, I'm looking further into it.

Comment: Another rundeck issue found [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/421), the issues seem to suggest that the exception is normal and does not indicate an error. Try moving `geteway.upload(path.toFile());` to its own try-catch before the `moveToSaveLocation(path, directoryName);` try-catch-finally and see if that works or the error persists.

Comment: I added to try/catch block `try {String upload = geteway.upload(path.toFile());} catch (Exception e) { moveToSaveLocation(path, directoryName); System.out.println(" " + e); }`  Still I see the   `jsch Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed` is getting logged

Comment: Right, I was saying move `geteway.upload(path.toFile())` to its own try-catch, so something like: `try {String upload = geteway.upload(path.toFile());} catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(" " + e); } /* */ try { moveToSaveLocation(path, directoryName); } catch { /* not sure what to catch */ } finally { /* your finally code */ }` -- I was saying that the issues on github were saying that `jsch Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed` is not cause for alarm, it throws that exception normally when the socket is closed.

Comment: You should try my code above and see if the file is uploaded to the server even though jsch logs `jsch Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed`.

Comment: Thanks John, is there any way we can hide the log. That particular statement

Comment: Did it work? I'm not aware of a way to hide the jsch log but you can always not output anything if you catch the exception.

Comment: It works. Still see the logging socket closed, ignoring it. However need to verify whether files are getting uploded to sftp server in code itself. I can move the logic to move files once files are uploaded to SFTP server successfully.